# Profile page badge information is contradictory

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, profile-page

In the Profile tab's badge list area, the title count is updated before the area it's a title of.
(the image makes it clear)

[image: profile-page-badge-area]

Comment: Caching?  How long ago was the badge awarded?

Comment: @psubsee2003 It was someone else's profile I noticed. So no other info. Point is, they're right next to each other. In fact one is the title of the other, so they should really show the same info. Or, is it generally accepted that this is ok based on it being caching?

Comment: I don't necessarily think having the profile show 2 different numbers for the same value in 2 places in close proximity is good.  But you have to expect some level of caching.  It could have simply been minutes or seconds since it was awarded (so bad timing on your part).  But if it took a long while to synch back up, that is less than ideal.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Fair point. Was just reporting what I saw. Is this perhaps likely to be the same *delay* as when a user already has badges showing there and a newly earned badge is delayed from showing in that area? (Unfortunately after seeing it I had to go out so couldn't monitor when it changed).

Answer (score 3):

This is a caching issue.

The actual list of badges is cached for 30 minutes, so can take some time to catch up.

Comment: Caching or no caching, at least don't show misleading count in the section title, i.e. put the count of cached badges in there. I don't think it would break anything.